# Find the number of subsets $A$ of $S= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$ such that: $x\in A\wedge 2x\in S\implies 2x \in A$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, alternative-proof, set-partition

> Find number of subsets $A$ of $S= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$ such that: $$x\in A\;\;\;\wedge \;\;\;2x\in S\;\;\;\implies \;\;\;2x \in A$$

**Solution:** Let $A= X\cup Y$ where $X \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $Y\subseteq \{6,7,8,9,10\}$.

- If $|X|= 0$ then we have $32$ possibilities for $Y$ and the same for $A$.
- If $|X| = 1$ (so we have $3$ choises for $X$) then we have $|Y|\geq 1$ so we have $3\times 2^4  = 48$  possibilities for $A$;
- If $|X| = 2$ then if $X= \{2,4\}$ we have $16$ choises for $Y$ else we have $|Y|\geq 2$ so we have ${3\choose 2}\times 2^3= 24$ possibilities for $A$ so in total in this case $40$ posibilities;
- If $|X| = 3$ then we have $16+2\cdot 8 + 4= 36$ possibilities for $A$.
- If $|X| = 4$ then we have $2\cdot 8 +4= 20$ possibilities for $A$;
- If $|X| = 5$ then we have $|Y|\geq 3$ so we have $1\times 2^2=4 $   possibilities for $A$.

So in total $\boxed{180}$ possibilities.

*Any shorter solution?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partition $S$ into sets that include all the numbers forced to be in $A$ if the least one is, so $\{1,2,4,8\},\{3,6\},\{5,10\},\{7\},\{9\}$.  For each subset of $k$ elements you have $k+1$ choices for how many elements to include in $A$ because once you include one you must include the larger elements, but you can include none.  $5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2=180$

Comment: An answer so elegantly framed that it made JMoravitz and me delete ours :-)

Comment: Is the logic behind k+1 this: consider B = {1,2,4,8}. Clearly ϕ ∈ B. Now, if we select any element from B, all the elements present to the right of it must be included in the subset. This yields k+1.